# Reading lookup column using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have to read values from two lookup fields. I am getting values with one of them but for the other it shows `undefined`.

```
$.ajax({
        url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Certifications')/Items?$filter="+filterById+"&$select=Title,Subsystem/ID,Subsystem/Title,Belongs_x0020_To/Title,Belongs_x0020_To/ID&$expand=Subsystem,Belongs_x0020_To",
        type: "GET",     
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
        //alert(data.d.results[0].Belongs_x0020_To);
        //alert(data.d.results[0].Belongs_x0020_To);
        //alert(data.d.results[0].Title);           
        }
```

Comment: Which one is undefined `Belongs_x0020_To` or others?

Comment: Pro tip, do a `console.dir(data)` in the success method to get the returned object printed to the console in for example Chrome. Then you can see how the object is composed

Comment: data.d.results[0].Belongs_x0020_To.Title and data.d.results[0].Belongs_x0020_To.ID is undefined

Comment: I guess your `$filter="+filterById+"` is returning some `null ` `Belongs_x0020_To`. Can you check it manually in the list @vikashkumar

Comment: If it is null, i thought it should show null value bt it showed undefined. When I added some values to those columns then it worked.

Comment: It is expected I guess. if `Belongs_x0020_To` is `null` then `Belongs_x0020_To.ID` must be `undefined` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

For checking your internal names:

Goto the List\Library settings page listing all fields (also works on ContentType definition)

and run the F12 code:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))
.forEach(function(a){
  if(a.href.indexOf('Field=')>0) 
      console.log(a.innerHTML,'=',a.href.split('Field=')[1].split('&Fid=')[0]);
 })
```

I have it under a [BookmarkLet](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) link, ready to use in any site I browse to.

A Standard TASKS list logs:

[image]

iFIELDS

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that you just have the wrong column name (the naming in SharePint sometimes aapears a little chaotic). 
The best way is to give out the URL (via console.log() or alert() ) and than just display the result in the browser. 
There you can see how the fields are named.

If this won't help:
If you want to access single fields of a lookup content type it sometimes just working if you integrate them in the column.

- Go to List => List Settings => YourContentTypeColumn
- Scroll down to "*Add a column to show each of these additional fields*"
- Check the columns you you need to access

I have no idea why this sometimes is needed (and sometimes not).